# Is it a good practice to override implementation of ServletContextListener?

Tags: java, web-services, servlets, jax-ws

I have developed a web service using JAX-WS and in the web.xml i had this servlet context listener registered.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

But, now i have some specific function to be done when the web service is UP and when web service is DOWN. The only way i could think of, was to create a `ServletContextlistener` and and add it in `web.xml`.

But this would override the one which was specified (as shown above `<listener>` tag).

My worry in this case is that `WSServletContextListener` might be already implementing the `ServletContextListener` methods and must be doing specific work in it.

I tried to extend `WSServletContextListener` class but its final so cannot. Another way is that i can take `WSServletContextListener` as instance member into my listener class and wrap all methods provided by it. But is that good practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your own listener and declare it in a new `<listener>..</listener>` tag. The two listeners should be invoked in the order they are specified in web.xml.

Answer (score 1):

You may declare several listeners, they will be invoked in the order they are defined in `web.xml`:

```
<listener>
   <listener-class>com.example.First</listenerclass>
</listener>
<listener>
   <listener-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
   <listener-class>com.example.Last</listener-class>
</listener>
```